# Hensel's Lemma when P cannot be raised to an integer power

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to solve the problem $x^2 ≡ 10\pmod{135}$. I know that I need to use both Hansel's Lemma and the Chinese Remainder Theorem to solve this.

So far, I believe I need to start with Hansel's Lemma as $135$ does not have $3$ co-prime factors. $135$ can be simplified to $5\cdot 3^3$. How do I account for this leading $5$? Is it legal to divide the entire equation by 5 here?

Comment: Solve $x^2\equiv1\bmod3$, lift to $x^2\equiv10\bmod{27}$ via Hensel, and solve $x^2\equiv 0\bmod5$ and combine with CRT.

Comment: Why do you need Hensel?  The numbers are so small...just work $\pmod {27}$ and $\pmod 5$ separately.

Comment: Use `\pmod{135}`, which gives you the parentheses *and* the correct spacing, all at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure what you mean. If you want to solve this using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, then you solve $x^2\equiv 10\pmod{5}$, and $x^2\equiv 10\pmod{27}$; then you take the (up to) four combinations of solutions you get to find the solutions modulo $135$ that correspond to the pairs.

To solve $x^2\equiv 10\pmod{5}$, note that this is $x^2\equiv 0\pmod{5}$, so you just get $x\equiv 0\pmod{5}$.

Now, to solve $x^2\equiv 10\pmod{27}$, you *can* try to use Hensel’s Lemma to lift the solutions. You first solve $x^2\equiv 10\pmod{3}$, and then you lift the each solution to modulo $9$ and then each of those to modulo $27$. In fact, it’s easy to just start at $9$: $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{9}$ has solutions $x=1$ and $x=-1$. Then to lift them to modulo $27$, we note that $f(x)=x^2-10$ has $f’(x)=2x$. This is not zero modulo $9$ at $1$ or at $-1$, so you can lift both solutions uniquely to solutions modulo $27$. With the usual formula you get that the solution $x\equiv1\pmod{9}$ lifts to $x\equiv 19\pmod{27}$.

You can now use the Chinese Remainder Theorem for this solution: you are looking for an $x$ such that
$$\begin{align*}
x\equiv 0&\pmod{5}\\
x\equiv 19&\pmod{27}
\end{align*}$$
which gives you a solution modulo $135$.

You do the same with the solution $x\equiv -1\pmod{9}$. Say you get that this lifts to $x\equiv a\pmod{27}$. Then you use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to look for an $x$ such that
$$\begin{align*}
x&\equiv 0\pmod{5}\\
x&\equiv a\pmod{27}
\end{align*}$$
to get the corresponding solution modulo $135$.